# How to Register Agility Instance with CommitStream

Tags: versionone

I have a CommitStream server from Repository https://github.com/openAgile/CommitStream.Web and would like to link Agility with CommitStream using InstanceID as per https://github.com/openAgile/CommitStream.Web/blob/develop/doc/install.md#how-to-configure-an-on-premise-build-of-versionone-to-point-to-your-commitstream-instance

When the Agility instance connects to the CommitStream server, it's getting "Could not find instance with id ..." error.

Has anyone dealt with this problem before?

When Agility is configured to talk to the public CommitStream server (commitstream.v1host.com) the request is executed without error.